# Sending different body via Amazon SES Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon-SES api for sending email to clients. It's very successfull but i have to send different body for each client. When i start to send mails about 200.000 clients, how the code below look like ? Is it loop 200.000 times or can i prepare an object and send one time (like n:n system, now it's 1:n).

```
var clientList=new List<String>(); //200.000 mail adress
foreach(var to in clientList)
{
        SendEmailRequest email = new SendEmailRequest();
        email.Message = new Message();
        email.Message.Body = new Body();
        email.Message.Body.Html = new Content(bodyhtml);
        email.Message.Subject = new Content(subject);

        email.WithDestination(new Destination() { ToAddresses = new List<String>() { to } })
        .WithSource("mysite@mysite.com")
        .WithReturnPath("mysite@mysite.com");

        SendEmailResponse resp = client.SendEmail(email); //that's 1:n
}

SendEmailResponse resp = client.SendEmail(emailList); //that's n:n but it's a wrong usage
```

How can i send n:n algorithm in Amazon SES ?

Application is Asp.net MVC 3. So can i use Asynchronous Controller ? Is it good idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have production access for [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) already (see [What should I do after I'm finished testing and evaluating Amazon SES?](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#10)) and a sufficiently increased *Sending Quota* to send 200.000 mails/day in the first place (see [How Amazon SES Sets Sending Limits](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ManagingActivity.PlanningAhead.html)), the respective limits are documented for the [SendEmail](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html) action:

> The total size of the message cannot exceed 10 MB.
>
> Amazon SES has a limit on the total number of recipients per message:
>   **The combined number of To:, CC: and BCC: email addresses cannot exceed
>   50**. If you need to send an email message to a larger audience, you can divide your recipient list into groups of 50 or fewer, and then call
>   Amazon SES repeatedly to send the message to each group. *[emphasis mine]*

**Please note**: It is strictly recommended to use `Bcc:` only for this kind of mass mailing operation, else your users will see their mail addresses exposed to each other and I can guarantee they won't be amused at all!

So you *could* prepare mails with 50 `Bcc:` recipients at a time, dropping the outbound mail amount for your use case to about 4.000, which is a considerable improvement already. **However**, please note a respective AWS Team response to [Increase sending limit, and question on FAQ](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=275868#275868):

> if you're sending to multiple ISPs [...], I would recommend
>   sending to one address at a time since **certain ISPs are sensitive
>   about multiple addresses on the BCC: line in large quantities**. *[emphasis mine]*

Whether or not this warning applies depends on your use case as usual (e.g. you might be able to shard the mails by ISP etc.).

Doing it asynchronously is fine and likely useful, but you need to ensure to stay within your *Maximum Send Rate* (mails/second) limit as well. These limits are visible in the SES tab of the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), but available via the API as well of course (see [Monitoring Your Sending Limits](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ManagingActivity.SendingLimits.html) for details).

Comment: yeah i know Sending Quota Limits. 200.000 is an example number by the way. My one client have 20.000 user(But it can be 200.000 there is no limit). i just wanna mail body starts with usernames for each user while sending marketing mails.

Comment: @ErayAydoğdu: If your mail bodies differ there is nothing you can do but send one mail at a time; as mentioned already, you can do this asynchronously though, if you stay within your _Maximum Send Rate (mails/second)_.